# xPage looses session when opened in multiple tabs

Tags: xpages

We have a very complicated page with a bunch of partial refreshes going on getting data from several sources and utilizing DOJO and jQuery . Everything works as it should with no problem. 
However, when the page is opened multiple times in the same browser on different tabs its seems to lose its session somehow. The partial refreshes don't work anymore and it keeps executing the before and afterPageLoad. 
Everything client-side still works, but any calls to the server end up doing nothing.
This happens more when we duplicate the page very fast, if the page is allowed to load fully, the problem seems less frequent. 
Telling the browser not to cache seems to make it worse, so it probably has to do with too much traffic.
The pages does use a lot of viewScopes to store data, but no sessionScopes.

Any tips where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: "the page is opened multiple times" - how?

Comment: By opening a new tab in the browser (chrome) and opening the url, or by duplicating the tab

Comment: use firebug/developer toolbar to track network responses of partial refreshes

Comment: I tried that again and watches a bit closer this time. The post gets send (same as when all functions correctly) , and the server returns data. This is however the same as the last data he send before the problem occurred.
So it seems the partial refresh does work, but the server returns the worn (old) data. I did try all the caching settings, but the problem stays.

Comment: what you say may be caused by proxy between you and server. is there a proxy?

Comment: No, i even tried it on 2 other servers on another network (windows and linux), and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you losing viewScopes or the whole session? (For an application that requires authentication, you would be prompted to authenticate again when fully refreshing the page. It doesn't sound like that's happening, but I'm not certain.)

Xsp Properties has a setting to determine how many pages to store either in memory or to disk for each page for the current session. Because the current session means the browser session, you might be opening so many pages it dumps the page, so will also dump the viewScope for the earliest tabs. Even if it's the same URL, it will treat it as a separate page if it's a different tab. The number of pages kept is stored on the persistence tab of Xsp Properties. I can't remember what the default is, but 16 rings a bell. It should be documented in XPages Portable Command Guide and possibly Mastering Xpages Second Edition.

Comment: Yes, the whole session is controlled by viewscopes, we never do a full refresh. When we do a full refresh there is no re-authentication, so the server session is still there.
I will check out the number of Pages and try increasing it.

Comment: Default is 4 in 8.5.3 and 16 in 9.0, I believe. Can lead to loss of data as Paul points out.

Comment: I increased the number of pages, but the problem remained. As I said in another comment, it seams like the server does return data, but it is the wrong 9previous) data, as if he is reading it from a cache. So probably the partial refresh does work, but it always ges the same dat from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was the page persistence after all. I changed it to 40 and this time I restarted the HTTP task (neglected that the last time). 
I can now load other pages without any problems.
Now if I load 40 pages fast, reloading before the page has finished loading, the first one stops responding. If I load it 'normally' 40 times everything works as it should.
seems like the server can't handle the quick reloads.