# XPages: beforePageLoad runs more than once... Why?

Tags: java, event-handling, scope, managed-bean

We have this XPages application that has one master page (say M.xsp) and several sub-pages, all in separate iframes on the master page (loaded as A.xsp, B.xsp and C.xsp in separate tabs). The application runs fine, generally speaking. Each sub-page shouldn't interfere with the other pages, and as far as I know, it doesn't. Some page-dependent data is stored in viewScope variables, but for the most important parts we developed Managed Beans, with their data mostly in view-scope too.

Now, what we see is the following:

1. on page A, we do several clicks and some AJAX calls occur to fetch data from the server
2. we switch to page B, we do 3 AJAX requests for data to the server
3. we switch back to page A, we do one click to fetch some data again, and a beforePageLoad event occurs! Needless to say, the page is still loaded.
4. on the same page A, we do a new click to fetch different data, and beforePageLoad is triggered again!

viewScope is lost, my page-dependent bean is lost, very strange.

We checked, but changing the amount of memory dedicated to XPages didn't change anything.

XPages 9.0.1, browser-only.

Can someone please explain this behaviour: how come beforePageLoad is repeatedly executed? How can we prevent it?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think my problem is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304249/xpage-looses-session-when-opened-in-multiple-tabs : page A and all its memory seems to disappear completely. Investigating further...

Answer (score 0):

Twas indeed related to the max number of pages in memory. Every time an item in a list on page B was clicked, a sub-page (B1) was loaded in yet another iframe, using a URL with the item as parameter. Many clicks in the list forced many pages to load, causing all other pages disappear from memory. So when we moved back to page A and triggered some partial refresh there, it was as if the the page was new to the runtime environment.

I rewrote the sub-page B2 to stay in memory, and do a partial refresh itself when the list value changes. Quite a lot faster, and no unnecessary page drops.